# Ordinal hash function

Tags: computer-science, ordinals, hash-function

Suppose I have a set of integers from 0 to 100.
Is there a non-invertible operation where the result is guaranteed to have the same ordinality as the input?

In other words, given `0 < 1 < 2,...`, is there a function $H(x)$ which would result in: $H(0) < H(1) < H(2)$, whilst retaining the property that if both $H$ and $H(n)$ are known, $n$ cannot be trivially calculated (other than with a binary-search)

I've been attempting to use modulo-exponentiation, but I cannot see how to force it to produce the correct order.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by trivially calculated, but knowing $H$ and $H(n)$, you can recover $n$ in $n$ steps : calculate $H(0),...H(k)$ until you find $H(n)$. As $H$ is strictly increasing, it is injective and so this procedure will give you $n$

Comment: @Max you can recover $n$ in $log2(n)$ steps by using a binary search. Trivial, in this case, means plugging numbers directly into an inverse function, instead of iterating over a search space.

Comment: With a set so small, even brute-force search is *fast*.

Comment: The answer to the question as stated is 'no': order preserving maps are always injective (as max pointed out) and hence invertible. You know this, given your last comment: the binary search you describe will give you the inverse function in the form of a lookup table. It seems that the question is if there is a map $H$ for which the description of the inverse cannot be further compressed than that? An easy way to achieve that would be to just pick 100 random integers in some interval, sort them and call them H(0), ... H(100).